# Writing into memory with loop scope variable and accessing it from outside

Tags: c, string, memory

### Background:

---

This all started with a program my friend wrote using file.

Skipping other details, I am focussing here in what actually attracted my attention.

1. There are text in the file which needs to be extracted as string.
2. The strings may be of different lengths.
3. To achieve this and not to spend a single byte extra, he used dynamic memory allocation. He     first counted the size and then created a string of adequate size with malloc and then inserted the characters in the target string.

It's good, but I tend to think if there is another way to store the characters in the string without any extra byte.

I came with following program:

### Code:

---

/* For simplicity, instead of file, I used another string "c" here, from where the data need to be copied. Consider ch as a read character from File.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

void main()
{
char *s,*p;
char c[4] ="abc";

char q[2] = "";
s=q;

int i;
for(i=0;c[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    char ch = c[i];
    int len = strlen(s);
    char p[len+2];
    strcpy(p,s);
    p[len]=ch;
    p[len+1]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",p);
    s=p;
}
char t[strlen(s)+1];
strcpy(t,s);

printf("%s\n",t);  //EDIT for understanding: If I print s here it prints garbage, 
                          but if I see the value of s through debugger, it gives
                          correct value?
}
```

### Understanding:

---

1. The string p is scoped to for loop, and for each iteration we are getting a new definition for it.
2. The starting address of the string is saved to variable s, that's why even when the code goes out of scope the memory is accessible, which is used in deciding the size of string when new character is encountered.

### Questions:

---

1.If my understanding above is correct, something is missing. I am saying this because instead of strcpy s to t and printing t (which gives correct O/P), if I directly try to print s, it prints garbage. I am not sure about this behaviour?

2.Is there any chance for memory corruption in this program?

P.S.: I understand that multiple strcpy() is over killing, hence the program is not optimized, but just asking this question to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Please don't use `void main()`; it is not sanctioned by the C standard or the Microsoft documentation.  The correct return type is `int`.  You're invoking _undefined behaviour_; anything can happen and it is OK.  Anything includes 'it works as wanted', but that's an accident which might be changed at any time.  For example, if you added a new block with a new variable in its scope and you wrote to that array, you might well overwrite the space previously used for `p`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, gcc was also giving me warning .. I'll remind this..!!

Answer (score 1):

Once a variable's lifetime is over the compiler is free to reuse the memory as it sees fit. Your retention of a pointer to the "old" p when you create a "new" p (next time round the loop, and after the end of loop) is not guaranteed to work at all. I'd not expect this work reliably, it's quite likely that the old and new ps may end up overlapping.

Whether you use strcpy or any other technique the continual shuffling of data is going to cost a lot in comparison with a simple use of malloc and where necessary occasional reallocations.

Comment: Thanks djna, yes I understand it'll cost a lot and should not be done in practice, but from this some curiosity arose, hence asked here.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` s and p are defined as pointers: `char *s, *p`  later after the for loop you ask about printing s and getting garbage that is because `s` is a pointer and printf is attempting to print that address, either use: `printf("%p", s);` to print address stored in s or `printf("%c", *s);` to print character pointed to by s.

Within the for loop you have defined a variable named `p[len+2]` this definition shadows the declaration in `main`.  In general this is a bad practice.  Did you really mean to 1) define a second version of p or 2) do you want to store information at the location pointed to by p.

If 1) rename p to something else and your bug will be obvious; if 2) allocate some storage for p to point to and then fill it in from your for loop.

Hope that I understand your intent and hope that this helps.